# How to add or sub timezone directly in MySQL

Tags: mysql, timezone

I got two columns in database, one is for saving timestamp, another is for saving timezone like "+8", "-5" string, I restore the date by using `DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(start_time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')`, is there any function in MySQL to calculate timezone like `start_time INTERVAL timezone`.

for example

```
start_time int 1491369437
timeonze char +8
```

User save 2017-01-01 08:00:00 and +8, I want to change it back to UTC so it should be 2017-01-01 00:00:00.

Comment: Please add your table schema some example data and expected output

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for your ask, I already add the example

Comment: ive added a answer.

Answer (score 1):

DATETIME 2017-01-01 08:00:00 is 1483254000 Unix time

You can use the function CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz) for this.

read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

UTC is +0:00 so you need this in the to_tz

**Query**

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(1483254000), "+8:00", "+0:00");
```

**Result**

```
CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(1483254000), "+8:00", "+0:00")  
---------------------------------------------------------
2017-01-01 00:00:00
```